# Swiveling a Rectangle or Cylinder

Tags: geometry

I am looking for some concise way of describing a geometric transformation. For the purpose of this question I will refer to it as a *swivel*. To perform a swivel on some shape, you would make some kind of planar cut ( or linear for 2D shapes ) through the shape, separating the shape into two parts. One part would then be rotated about an axis orthogonal to the plane of the cut by some degree. The particular *swivel* being done on the shape would be defined in terms of the definition of the plane of the cut and the amount rotated. An example with a rectangle could be to cut the rectangle from some point on one of its long edges to some other point on its other edge and rotate one of the pieces 180 degrees, resulting in the rectangle being bent.

**My question is, is there already a name for this sort of transform, or at least a better, more concise way to talk about it?**

I have really only thought of this *swiveling* in terms of rectangles, rectangular prisms, and cylinders, so if it doesn't generalize well, that is why.

---

Here is an example using rectangles:

[image]

Comment: There is a LaTeX guide for beginners around this site somewhere. If you google it, it'll come up. This is how you get in-line formulas.

Comment: AS it relates to the main question, you need to specify how the rotation happens. Rotating 180 degres to me does not seem to result in a rectangle of any kind. I'm imagining two trapezoids.

Comment: @Alfred Yerger Yes the transform would take the rectangle and make two trapazoid.

Comment: A good free program for drawing geometric diagrams is GeoGebra: https://www.geogebra.org/download

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thanks for the tip. This is just what I was looking for!

Comment: I drew the following GeoGebra diagram which I think is what you mean by a "swivel" for a quadrilateral swiveled by $180^{\circ}$: http://ggbm.at/huvkB69U